# Software too small on 4K resolution screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, resolution, 4k-resolution

So, I've had this laptop for some time, and am trying to use the software "ChessBase 12". However, everything is *way* too small. I know that this is a conflict with the 4K resolution of the monitor.

### **My Question:**

How can I force an application that wasn't built for 4K resolution (like CB12) to display correctly? Everything is pretty much 1/4 the size it should be.

### **The Catch:**

Messing with the resolution/display settings on my laptop is not an option, as I want the 4K resolution everywhere else. Plus, the last time I tried messing with those settings, it triggered some major OS conflict and slowed my system to a crawl. System Restore, PC Reset/Refresh, and Factory Settings didn't fix the issue. I had to boot into recovery mode and reset from there and it finally fixed it.

### **What I've Tried:**

I have tried troubleshooting, and doing that DPI Scaling thing, but it doesn't work. Also, the option to set the resolution in properties is grayed out.

### **My Specs:**

- Lenovo Y50-70 Gaming Laptop (64-Bit)
- Windows 10 (Pre-Installed)
- 16GB RAM
- Intel Quad-Core i7 Processor
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M GPU
- Over 700GB Free Space
- 4K UHD Screen (3840 x 2160)

Comment: Can you clarify "didn't work" re: DPI scaling (and was that applied to the CB12 window or the screen)?  It is actually displaying correctly, that is just very small on a 4K display.  You need something to magnify (DPI scaling) the window.  Have you explored utilities to do that?

Comment: @fixer1234 The DPI scaling was applied to CB12, and did not change anything. I couldn't tell the difference. And I wasn't aware of utilities for that. Google has been no help to me.

Comment: I'm on Linux, so can't recommend a specific product.  However, Googling terms like "window magnifier" bring up products like [this](http://www.blacksunsoftware.com/screenmagnifier.html).  This style of product you would size and position over the CB12 window.  There are probably products where you can select a window to magnify.

Comment: I'd also complain to the authors if its a paid software. I do believe there's some minior tweaks that might be needed for DPI awareness.